# Issue with Navigation Bar on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios10, ios9.3

I am working on an application which needs to be supported from iOS 10. I see the strange issue with navigation bars with Xcode 9.2 and 9.3. I added a view controller on the storyboard and when executing the application on iPhone 5 with iOS 10, I don't get to see the navigation bars, but the same is working on another device with iOS 11. But I can see the navigation bar on storyboards when selected topbar as transculent navigation bar and also embedded in a navigation controller. So what might be the issue?

Comment: It is difficult to say anything without seeing the actual structure in Storyboard. Also, maybe you specified programatically to detect device or iOS version and show or hide navigationBar? Show some screens, paste some code. It will be easier to help that way.

Comment: Thanks, Starsky... Was able to fix that finally.. that is due to the navigation bar extension I had written to override the height... removing that extension worked fixed the issue.

Comment: Kudos to you for figuring it out yourself ;)